# How do you call: Ln(Xt/Xt-1)?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, interpretation, logarithm

What is the best word/ phrase of describing the following: 
 Ln(Xt/Xt-1)?

Is that: 
A: natural log of differences? 
B: natural log of growth rates? 
C: Something else??

The reason I need to know the precise answer is because of my thesis. I transformed variables to ln(Xt/Xt-1), but don't what it is called. I've to describe something like: variables have been transformed to their logarithmic [insert correct answer]. I'm confused by other papers....

Comment: "Log difference"?

Comment: The notation is ambiguous: obviously you don't mean $X_t/X_t-1\cong 0$ (which is a literal reading of what you have posted), but do you mean $$\frac{X_t}{X_t-1}$$ or $$\frac{X_t}{X_{t-1}}?$$ Please edit the question to clarify this crucial point.

Comment: The latter. Thus, the log of the return.

Answer (score 0):

While this depends on what $X_t$ signifies, what you're probably looking for is called the [logarithmic return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Logarithmic_or_continuously_compounded_return) transformation, a.k.a force of interest. If your thesis is in Econometrics or Finance, just call them "log-returns" and most of your audience will know what you mean.